# Label in UITableViewCell is not getting accessed in .m file

Tags: uitableview, ios7, label

I have a tableview in my view controller. I took one protype cell in which I created a label and connected it to the tableVieCell.h file. The problem is when I try to access the label in my view to get it loaded with the textfield input, I am not getting the label component. Please check.  Here is my MyCell.h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *celltextField;
@end
```

here is my viewController.h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyCell.h"


@interface ViewController :UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
NSMutableArray *contacts;
}

- (IBAction)leftBtn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)rightBtn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)SendBtn:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tabV1;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;
@end




#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
{
    MyCell *cell;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController




- (void)viewDidLoad {

    contacts= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    }

        -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) textField{
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
    return contacts.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//    [cell.zoomButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigateAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//    cell.zoomButton.tag=indexPath.row;

    cell= [[MyCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}


//    cell.textLabel.text=contacts[indexPath.row];
   cell.label2.text=[contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;

}

- (IBAction)leftBtn:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)rightBtn:(id)sender {
}
- (IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender {
}
-(void)someMethod:(UIButton *)sender{
}
- (IBAction)SendBtn:(id)sender {
//    if (_leftBtn.tag==1) {
//        cell.label1.text=_txtField.text;
//        
//    }else{
//        cell.label2.text=_txtField.text;
//    }
[self->contacts addObject:_txtField.text];
//    label2.text=_txtField.text;
[_tabV1 reloadData];

_txtField.text=@"";
}
@end
```

Comment: Please provide code, it's hard to help you with only that much information.

Comment: Sure. 
Actually, I have a tableView in my storyboard. I took one cell and assigned tableViewCell class to it. And I placed one label in that cell.
Now I have a text field outside the table view. I want the text which is typed in the text field to be appeared in the label.

Comment: @ Florian Koch Did you get it now?

Comment: sorry, i just wanted to give you a hint on how to improve your question, so that it's easier for others to help you out - I have no experience with iOS development, so sadly i can't help you personally

Comment: @Florian Koch. No problem. Thank you

Comment: @Florian Koch do you know someone who can answer my iOS questions or can you suggest someone to answer...I really want to learn things. 
Thank you

Comment: i added a little bounty to this question to attract attention, maybe this helps

Comment: Thank you so much... @Florian Koch you are the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
cell= [[MyCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

to this

```
MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: If I change that... will I able to access cell's label in controller.m file?

Comment: @k.mand why did you mark that as solution when it causes errors for you?

Comment: @k.mand : What kind of error are you getting when executing code recommended by Warif ? Make sure you have imported #import "MyCell" in your view controller. Because the above code should work fine. And also check wether the "identifier" you set for the prototype cell is "cell" and and check wether you have set the class for the prototype cell as "MyCell" in storyboard. Then try again.

Comment: @Bharath I have some doubts.. Please ping me at kalyanimandadi93@gmail.com if you find some time. Please.